# Play radio stream from internet

Tags: c#, naudio, windows-media-player, internet-radio

I'm trying to play audio from a stream. It's radio over internet. For this i was using the WMPLib (windows media player library).

It works for some formats, but not all.

For example for this format it works:

http://www.qmusic.nl/live/qmusic_itunes.m3u

But this one doesn't get played:

http://www.radioveronica.nl/player/radioveronica.pls

You can try both links in windows media player itself.

My question is, what library would be able to support atleast both formats?

Answer (score 0):

The second one isn't a stream. If you are using Firefox, install Firebug and check the http-requests that are performed by the site. This way, you can get the URL of the actual stream that is played on the site, and that should work.

Comment: Hi, in which pane can I see the requests?

Comment: In the Net pane, i just tried it myself, did find the stream, but this one didn't work for me either. I don't know how the stream is played by the Flash player on the site. However I've done the same thing in my own app and mostly it worked.

Comment: In your app? What does your app use for audio lib?

Comment: In my experience, most stations also publish links to their streams.  http://www.radioveronica.nl/luister/online-radio

Comment: builtin WPF MediaElement - so in the end, probably the same as yours

Comment: WMP doesnt support .pls format. Tried the link direcly on the WMP. So i'm gonna have to look for another lib than this one. Hope someone has an idea which one to use.

Comment: Where did you tried it? And what link? The one you gave was just the site.

Comment: This one contains a selection of streams offered by radio veronica: http://www.radioveronica.nl/luister/online-radio

Comment: Well i just tried them all in WMP by 'open url', and it keeps saying that it cant play this format. Although not exaclty with these words. So how are you playing them?

Comment: Tried them in VLC, couldn't find open file in WMP

Comment: Try right mouse button on the bar which is below the title bar. The menubar has been removed.

Comment: No, dont work for me either, pls is unsupported by WMP. There is a free addon available called "Open PLS"

Comment: Well, i need it integrated in the wmplib. Installing the addon won't make the lib work.

Comment: I thought so. Well, sorry this is it can't help you on this one :)

Comment: IMHO overkill for your purposes, but Gstreamer would probably do the trick

Comment: Parsing a PLS file is pretty simple, this is how Open PLS does it, looks like a single file does the trick. You could preprocess the pls and then send it to WMP.   http://openplsinwmp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/37545#538612

Comment: Ah okay, that's a good idea. Let me try that. I'll get back to you thanks!

Comment: Uri formats are not supported. To bad! Still searching for an alternative way to do this.